# EC2 to Lambda forwarding based on current usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, load-balancing, cold-start

I am having long cold start times on our Lambda functions. We have tried "pinging" the Lambdas to keep them warm but that can get costly and seems like a poor way to keep performance up. We also have an EC2 instance running 24/7. I could theoretically "mirror" all of our Lambda functions to our EC2 instance to respond with the same data for our API call. Our Lambdas are on https://api.mysite.com and our EC2 is https://dev.mysite.com.

My question is could we **"load balance?" traffic between the two**. (Create a new subdomain to do the following) To have our dev subdomain (EC2) respond to all requests up until a certain "requests per minute" is hit. Then start to route traffic to our dev subdomain (Lambda) since we have enough traffic coming in to keep the Lambdas hot. Once traffic slows down, we move the traffic back over to our EC2.. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would it get costly keeping Lambdas warm? We have literally thousands of Lambdas in our VPC which we keep warm using the ping strategy and the overall cost of keeping them warm is <$5.00/month.

Comment: @hephalump is there a limit to the number of different lambda functions you can have per account?  did you have to request an increase to have thousands?  i cant find this anywhere.  only concurrency limits.

Comment: @stuart there is no limit on the *number* of lambda functions, just the amount of storage they consume, 75GB max across all versions, but this can be increased.  See here for your accounts limits (change the region in the url as necessary):  https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home?region=us-east-1#!/services/lambda/quotas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not do that with AWS Load balancer. What you can do is setup cloudwatch trigger to the lambda function which will map api.mysite.com to the lambda load balancer dns. Similarly, you can add trigger for low traffic which will redo dns entry.

If you are aware of rise in traffic, you can scheduled instances. Else you can also try AWS Fargate.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You can also rewrite load balancer target group via lambda trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudwatch allows you to choose the number of triggers you wanna set for a lambda i.e. whenever an API is called, cloudwatch will trigger those many of the lambdas. This is one way you could achieve it. There's no way yet, to load balance between lambdas and instances.

You can configure your API to use Step functions which will orchestrate your lambda.